# Compare position of a string with an integer

Tags: c, string, int

Per example:

string:  1 2 3 4 5

I want to make a for loop to compare each of the string positions with an int provided by the user. I tried

if(atoi(string[i]) == value)

but this didn't seem to work, do I need to change it to the other way around? (the int into string, then strcmp?)
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably add some language to your question. We don't even know what language you are using so it's hard to help.

Comment: sorry, was kinda in a rush, so I forgot :b @KivakWolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this in C++.

`atoi` takes a `const char*` as an argument, but you're passing it a char.  What you would need to do is something like this:

```
std::string str(1, string[i]);
if(atoi(str.c_str()) == value)
...
```

Or you could skip the atoi altogether and just do

```
if(string[i]-48 == value)
...
```

This works because numerals start at ascii value of 48 and you're only checking one character at a time.

Disclaimer: I'm also assuming `string` is a char[] and therefore `string[i]` is a `char`

Comment: Nope, C actually :b, the ascii process worked tho, thanks a lot man :)

Comment: Actually, `string[i] - '0'` would also work and make it clearer what you're doing IMHO :-)

Comment: @BjornMunch yeah actually I like that better.  I don't want to edit though because the answer was already accepted.